# Bootcamp with Windows 10 can not change display resolution

Tags: display, bootcamp, windows

I installed Windows using BootCamp my MacBook Pro Mid-2010 on a separate hard drive running Windows 10. I have had issues playing all games on the OS, due to the game resolution being the same as my screen resolution, and I am unable to change it.

My display resolution is stuck at 1680 x 1050 in Windows, and I can't change it. I have all the drivers installed, by using both GeForce Experience AND the macOS / Bootcamp drivers from Apple. The issue is that I cannot change my system display resolution and in all games, it shows my graphics card as the "Microsoft Basic Render Driver" and not "GeForce GT 330M".

I have the latest (Latest drivers are from 2016) graphics drivers for my card (GeForce GT 330M).

When I go into a game like Overwatch, it shows the graphics card as "Microsoft Basic Render Driver" and not "GeForce GT 330M", so that may be related.

How can I validate I have the correct graphics drivers so I can change the resolution in Windows?

Comment: Did you install the Boot Camp Support Software that can be downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant? This probably is the same as [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). Also, was the separate drive a internal SATA drive or an external USB drive? Are you BIOS or EFI booting Windows 10?

Comment: I have the software, it is a 500GB external hard drive, and I am using EFI booting.

Comment: Great question, rather than closing it as unclear - I've edited to remove the side question and point out a couple items you might improve upon like specific details and how you updated the drivers.

Comment: @bmike Ok, I just edited my question to be more clear (hopefully).